# Extracting text in span element using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So this is the thing, I'm trying to extract some data from the SEC database using BeautifulSoup, I'm literally new at python but I been able to write the following code.

The idea is to use a list of quote symbols in a .txt and extract "the CIK" number of each company for further use.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
list_path = r"C:\Users\User1\Downloads\Quote list.txt"

with open(list_path, "r") as flist:
    for quote in flist:
        quote = quote.replace("\n", "")
        url = (r"https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=" + quote + 
        r"&type=10&dateb=&owner=exclude&count=100")
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        for company_info in soup.find_all("span", {"class" :"companyName"}):
            cik_code = company_info.string
            print(cik_code)
```

So far, the code above print "none" values for the string 'cik_code'. The element in html is the following:

```
<span class="companyName dm-selected dm-test">
      AAON INC 
      <acronym title="Central Index Key">CIK</acronym>
      #: 
      <a href="/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?
      action=getcompany&amp;CIK=0000824142&amp;owner=exclude&amp;count=100" 
      class="">0000824142 (see all company filings)</a>
</span>
```

The cik code is the last number: 0000824142, just before "(see all company filings)"

How can I set that number to the string cik_code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to go into the `<a>` tag that's inside the `<span>` tag.

```
for company_info in soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'companyName'}):
    cik_code = company_info.find_next('a').text.split(' ', maxsplit=1)[0]
    print(cik_code)
```

**Explanation:**

- `company_info.find_next('a')` returns:

> ```
>   <a href="/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?
>   action=getcompany&amp;CIK=0000824142&amp;owner=exclude&amp;count=100" 
>   class="">0000824142 (see all company filings)</a>
> ```

- `.text` returns:

> ```
> 0000824142 (see all company filings)
> ```

- `.split(' ', maxsplit=1)[0]` returns:

> `0000824142`

Comment: That worked perfectly, even though I don't know why. Thanks bro!

Comment: Just added an explanation to give you a better idea.